# Unable to connect to psql db

Tags: postgresql, go

I am trying to connect to a database, but getting an error when I make a curl request to the endpoint with the `GET` method. I double-checked with the user credentials and have granted full privileges and superuser permissions.
Following is the error I get when curl the endpoint:

```bash
santosh@pkg*$:curl -i localhost:8080/books/show
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /books
Date: Sat, 19 Nov 2022 12:09:52 GMT
Content-Length: 33

<a href="/books">See Other</a>.
```

The connection is established with the Database, when the request is made to the database these errors are triggered:

```bash
santosh@pkg*$:go run main.go 
Database connection successful.
2022/11/19 17:39:47 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:44324: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 35 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1()
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1850 +0xbf
panic({0x6960e0, 0x8e5630})
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:890 +0x262
database/sql.(*DB).conn(0x0, {0x7593d0, 0xc00011a000}, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1288 +0x53
database/sql.(*DB).query(0x6?, {0x7593d0, 0xc00011a000}, {0x6da967, 0x13}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 0x68?)
```

The main program:

```
var db *sql.DB

type Books struct {
    Isbn   string
    Title  string
    Author string
    Price  float32
}

func init() {
    var err error
    args := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d dbname=%s user='%s' password=%s sslmode=%s", "localhost", 5432, "bookstore", "santosh", "dts123", "disable")
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", args)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Creating Database %s", err)
    }
    if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Database connection succussful.")

}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", index)
    http.HandleFunc("/books", booksIndex)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/books", http.StatusSeeOther)
}

func booksIndex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "GET" {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(405), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM books")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
        return
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    bks := make([]Books, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        bk := Books{}
        err := rows.Scan(&bk.Isbn, &bk.Title, &bk.Author, &bk.Price)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
            return
        }
        bks = append(bks, bk)
    }
    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
        return
    }

}
```

I tried double-checking user privileges and database format and for order. All are in line with the code. The connection is established but fails with panic while querying the DB.

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you so much, That was in fact the issue. So foolish of me to miss such a tiny detail. Thanks a ton for such a quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not properly initializing the package-level `db` variable.

The `:=` operator, called "short variable **declaration**", declares and initializes a *new* variable in its block scope. Any variable with the same name in an outer scope will be "shadowed".

To properly initialize the package-level variable you can use plain [assignment](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignment_statements):

```golang
var db *sql.DB

func init() {
    args := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d dbname=%s user='%s' password=%s sslmode=%s", "localhost", 5432, "bookstore", "santosh", "dts123", "disable")

    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("postgres", args)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Creating Database %s", err)
    }
    // ...
}
```

Or you can use `:=` but then use a different variable name and make sure to use that for the assignment:

```golang
var db *sql.DB

func init() {
    args := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d dbname=%s user='%s' password=%s sslmode=%s", "localhost", 5432, "bookstore", "santosh", "dts123", "disable")

    _db, err := sql.Open("postgres", args)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Creating Database %s", err)
    }
    // ...

    db = _db // set "global"
}
```